# Do "transcription factor binding site" and "operator" mean the same thing?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, dna, gene-regulation

Can the terms "transcription factor binding site" and "operator" be used interchangeably in all contexts when referring to a DNA sequence, e.g. regardless of a cell type, whether or not the binding sequence is synthetic or natural etc.? If not, what are the differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you no doubt know, the term operator was coined by Jacob and Monod as part of the formalism they developed to explain the properties of certain mutants in the *lac* operon in *E. coli*. In physical terms it is indeed the site of binding of a transcription factor, the *lac* repressor.

My understanding is that technically it is best to restrict the use of this terminology to bacterial systems in which the idea of an operon is useful. I don't think it would be wise to extend it to cover any site in eukaryotic DNA where a transcription factor is shown to bind.

Comment: To add about it: I am working with transcription factors for a few years now, I have never heard of anybody using it in eukaroytes. The sites are simply called transcription factor binding site.